# Why do all my IIS 7 virtual directories get modified when I modify one?

Tags: iis, iis-7, redirect, virtual-directory, virtualdirectories

I recently upgraded a Windows Server 2003 with IIS 6 to Server 2008 and IIS 7. This server has over 200 virtual directories which are used to redirect to different pages on the site. The settings didn't seem to transfer over after the upgrade and I've been forced to go through and fix the redirect destination on each one by hand. However I just noticed that if I change the redirect destination on any virtual directory, all 200 other virtual directories get modified as well. I'm no IIS expert. Why is this happening and how do I prevent it?

Comment: You're probably modifying the settings on the parent directory; the interface is a bit strange.  Can you clarify what you're doing in what order in the interface?

Comment: I open IIS, then in the left pane I expand [My Server] > Sites > [mysite.com]. All the virtual directories are under that. I click on one of them and the header at the top of the window changes to reflect that I'm working on that virtual directory. In the right pane underneath the header I click HTTP Redirect, enter the url for the redirect and click Apply. After that, the redirect for all the virtual directories get set to the value I entered for that single virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert a virtual directory to an **"application"** (right click the virtual directory)

In IIS 7, I think, Virtual Directories do not have their own *"settings",* but **Applications** do.